Pausing WebBrowser animations in C# application
We're using the WebBrowser component to "embed" a web browser into our kiosk application. Service engineers use the component to test the internet, but they can also log into a Service Panel to log details of the work.
Unfortunately the default web page we have been asked to use (our company website) is full of nasty animations and a giant looping video which is spiking the CPU usage on our low-end hardware (Marketing, be cursed!).
The Microsoft documentation says to call WebBrowser::Stop but this only briefly pauses the animation, which then starts up again.

Can animations or looping videos be turned off?
Is it possible to tell the WebBrowser component to operate in some kind of "lighweight" mode which permanently pause animations or rendering large videos (maybe only showing the first frame of a video and permanently pausing animations)?


Try replacing the WebBrowser control with WebView2 and see if its better behaving? A starter on how to get it into Winforms i assume you are in.

Can you share a minimal reproducible example without personal privacy through GitHub?

@FeiXu: The questions already implies a MRE - put a WebBrowser component on a form, compile and then point the component to a website with lots of animations. Can the animations be turned off or minimised?

You can do this by modifying C# code to inject JavaScript scripts into the html. Here is an example that shows how to do it.
Firstly, write an event to inject a script into html to stop videos and animations:
private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (webBrowser1.Document != null)
    {
        string script = @"
    var video = document.getElementById('myVideo');
    video.pause();
    var box = document.querySelector('.box');
    var animationState = window.getComputedStyle(box).getPropertyValue('animation-play-state');
    box.style.animationPlayState = 'paused';
    ";
        webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("execScript", new object[] { script, "JavaScript" });
    }
}

Then, don't forget to bind this event in the initialization part of code, like this:
public Form1()
{
    InitializeForm();
  webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted +=
    new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted);
}


Is your problem being solved? It is hoped that you can give any feedback. @AlainD
